# Haskell: !! operator on variable

Tags: haskell

When i try to access a list element through a variable index i get an error:

```
Prelude> let x = 0
Prelude> let y = [1,2,3]
Prelude> y !! x

<interactive>:18:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    In the second argument of `(!!)', namely `x'
    In the expression: y !! x
    In an equation for `it': it = y !! x
```

The problem seems to be that the type of 0 is Num and the type of x is Integer, but how can i fix this ?
I tried to google the problem but had no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that GHCi is a bit more aggressive in what it defaults types of values to.  Just specify type signatures and you'll be fine:

```
> let x = 0 :: Int
> let y = [1, 2, 3]
> y !! x
1
```

This is caused by the [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).  There are dozens of answers here on SO that explain it in detail, along with a pretty complete explanation in that link.

Comment: @user2664856 Alternatively, you can use `genericIndex` which accepts any type that is an instance of `Integral` (not just `Int`), but that's probably not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not an `Int` by default, which is the type `!!` takes. Solution:

```
let x = 0 :: Int
let y = [1, 2, 3]
y !! x
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring x you can try using:

```
let x = 0 :: Int
```

To force it as type int, then y !! x should work